# input output in 64 bit assembly in linux

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, yasm

```
segment .data
n   times 100 db 0  ; n = scanf()
s   times 100 db 0 ; char s[100]
fmt db  "%s",0 
pfmt    db  "The input was %s",0x0a,0
extern  printf
extern  scanf

segment .text
global main
main:
    lea rdi,[fmt]
    lea rsi,[s]
    xor eax,eax
    call    scanf
    mov [n],rax
    xor eax,eax

    lea rdi,[pfmt]
    lea rsi,[n]
    xor eax,eax
    call    printf

    ret
```

I want to use scanf and printf in yasm in linux 64 bit, but this scanf is taking the input but there is no output at all, I have checked in gdb also its showing '001' in eax register or in [n] memeroy address as well. Is there any who can correct this please.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `[n]` together with the format specifier `%s`? The string you read with `scanf` is stored at `s`.

Comment: I want to store the input string in 'n' variable from eax, which i suppose to come from scanf call, am i correct going, pls guide me

Comment: `scanf` doesn't return the string; it returns the number of items that have been read (in this case 1). The string that has been read is stored at `s`. If you want to do a by-value copy of the string to some other piece of memory, then write a loop to do so.

Comment: ok, i am trying now